# If f(n) ∈ ω(g(n)), then 2 ^ f(n) ∈ ω(2 ^ g(n) )

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have to find whether the following is true or false:

If f(n) ∈ ω(g(n)), then 2 ^ f(n) ∈ ω(2 ^ g(n) )

I did the calculations f(n) = 1/n and g(n) = 1/n^2 and got the ans as false.

It should be :

If f(n) ∈ ω(g(n)), then 2 ^ f(n) ∈ Θ(2 ^ g(n) )

Could some one please verify this?

Comment: I was hoping for a moment this was APL

Comment: It seems counter-intuitive that if f dominates g then 2^f is bounded by 2^g (f could dominate g by a ridiculous amount).  What calculations did you do to establish the initial claim was false?

Comment: @Scott: It's counter-intuitive because the example functions are decreasing. One usually thinks of increasing functions when talking about `big-O` and `little-o` notations.

Comment: @ypercube: I meant that it was counterintuitive that a one-sided bound implied a two-sided bound.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, the `Θ` looks odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Statement:** `f(n) ≥ g(n) ⋅ k` for all `k` ⇒ `2^f(n) ≥ 2^g(n)⋅k` for all `k`.

Your counterexample is correct: `1/n ≥ k/n²` is true for all `k`. We can show this by taking the limit:

`limn → ∞ (1 / n) / (k / n²) = 1/k ⋅limn → ∞ n² / n = ∞`

However: `21/n ≥ 21/n² ⋅ k` is false. We can also show this by taking the limit:

`limn → ∞ 21/n / (21/n² ⋅ k) =
    = 1/k lim of 21/n - 1/n² =
    = 1/k lim of 2(n - 1) / n² = 1/k ⋅ 2⁰ =
    = 1/k`

The statement would only have been true if the limit was infinity.

A single counterexample is enough to prove that a statement is false, so you're done.